# In unity tag is not found in first drag

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a simple drag and drop unity game. When I drag the object for the first time it does not give score but when I drag it once again it gives score even if I am dropping at the wrong place. I am using tag to match desired objects

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class sh_score : MonoBehaviour {    
    static int score = 0;
    public Text scoreText;

    public GameObject ans_circle;
    public GameObject tag_circle;
    public GameObject tag_rectangle;
    public GameObject ans_rectangle;
    public GameObject ans_triangle;
    public GameObject tag_triangle;
    public GameObject ans_square;
    public GameObject tag_square;
    public GameObject ans_star;
    public GameObject tag_star;

    void Start()
    {
        score = score;

        if( (ans_circle == null || tag_circle == null) || (ans_rectangle  == null || tag_rectangle == null)|| (ans_square == null || tag_square == null) || (ans_triangle == null || tag_triangle == null)|| (ans_star == null || tag_star == null))
        {
            ans_circle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_circle");
            if (ans_circle != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_circle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("circle");
            if (tag_circle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("circle");
            }

            checkTagPlace();

            ans_rectangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_rectangle");
            if (ans_rectangle != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_rectangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("rectangle");
            if (tag_circle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("rectangle");
            }

            ans_triangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_triangle");
            if (ans_triangle != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_triangle = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("triangle");
            if (tag_triangle != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("triangle");
            }

            ans_star = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_star");
            if (ans_star != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_star = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("star");
            if (tag_star != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("star");
            }

            ans_square = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ans_square");
            if (ans_square != null)
            { Debug.Log("ans Find"); }

            tag_square = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("square");
            if (tag_square != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("square");
            }
        }    
    }

    void update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }

    public void IncrementScore()
    {    
        score = score + 9;
        score++;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }

    public void checkTagPlace()
    {
        Debug.Log("check function run");
        float circle_postion = tag_circle.transform.position.x;
        float circle_Tag_positon = ans_circle.transform.position.x;
        float triangle_position = tag_triangle.transform.position.x;
        float triangle_Tag_positon = ans_triangle.transform.position.x;
        float square_postion = tag_square.transform.position.x;
        float square_Tag_positon = ans_square.transform.position.x;
        float star_postion = tag_star.transform.position.x;
        float star_Tag_positon = ans_star.transform.position.x;
        float rectangle_position = tag_rectangle.transform.position.x;
        float rectangle_Tag_positon = ans_rectangle.transform.position.x;
        if ((ans_circle.transform.position.x == tag_circle.transform.position.x))
        {
            Debug.Log("found position");
            IncrementScore();    
        }
        else if ((ans_rectangle.transform.position.x == tag_rectangle.transform.position.x))
        {
            IncrementScore();
        }
        else if ((ans_square.transform.position.x == tag_square.transform.position.x))
        {
            IncrementScore();
        }
        else if (ans_triangle.transform.position.x == tag_triangle.transform.position.x)
        {
            IncrementScore();
        }

        else if (ans_star.transform.position.x == tag_star.transform.position.x)
        {
            IncrementScore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: void Update() needs to start with an upper case U

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 3):

I cannot post comments yet but

- You are calling `checkTagPlace` before having set all of your attributes it may be the cause of the bug.
- Searching gameObjects with tags this way may be a problem in the future if you have several objects with the same tag
- Usually to do what you want to do you want to use Colliders on your GameObject and the OnCollisionEnter/OnCollisionStay/OnTriggerEnter/OnTriggerStay functions (do not forget the upper case). Then you will be able to check if the "collisioned" GameObject have the correct tag.

Comment: Gave you an upvote because of your first bulletpoint, as that is an answer. It _might_ not be the correct one, but it is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem might be here:

```
if(ans_rectangle.transform.position.x == tag_rectangle.transform.position.x)
```

When you check to see if these positions (and the other if statements like this one) are equal, you are checking if they're *exactly* equal. Unless you have some controller which is discretizing the movements of your shapes, thats almost never going to happen.

I believe what you want is really something like this:

```
float epsilon=.001;
if(Math.abs(ans_rectangle.transform.position.x - tag_rectangle.transform.position.x)<epsilon)
```

Alternatively, you can give colliders to all of your shapes and actually check for collisions between the two shape types, perhaps using layer masks to keep from comparing shapes of dissimilar types.

I understand that this doesn't explain all the behavior you're seeing, but it might explain why it doesn't increment your score the first time.

Since you don't include the code which is enabling the dragging, we can't know if that is the problem or not.